# Nested arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

If i have a nested array lets say:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

I want to divide element wise so my output would be:

```
[5/1, 6/2, 7/3, 8/4]
```

Just using fractions to be clear on what i'm asking. Thank you

Comment: `[b/a for a,b in zip(*arr)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the zip() function:

```
d=[] #This is done to avoid name 'd' is not defined
arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
zipped = zip(arr[1], arr[0])
for i1,i2 in zipped:
    d.append(i1/i2)
```

Comment: Would you know If I had a large number of rows and wanted to use a for loop how would I accomplish this since I wouldn't be able to use zip?

Comment: If you don't want to use zip() you could iterate through the first list with enumerate() and then access the second list with the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with numpy.

Extract the second row, and divide it by the first row element wise:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
np.array(arr[1, :] / arr[0, :])
# [5.         3.         2.33333333 2.        ]
```

If instead you want to do it with a for loop:

```
[arr[1][i] / arr[0][i] for i in range(len(arr[0]))]
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what i would do if I had a large number of rows, and wanted to use a for loop?

Comment: I've edited my post to show a for loop approach as well, or I would use @luigigi's approach